# How to animate the height changing

Tags: android, animation

I have a simple card in my app and when the user click on it, I'm changing the height. This change of height I'd like to be animated, a smooth change of height.

```
@OnClick({R.id.emptyDescription})
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.emptyDescription:
            if(isCardCollapsed){

                emptyDescription.setMinimumHeight(400);

                cancelSaveLinear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                editDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                isCardCollapsed = false;
            } else {
                emptyDescription.setMinimumHeight(100);

                cancelSaveLinear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                editDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                isCardCollapsed = true;
            }

            break;
        case R.id.card_view:
            break;
    }
}
```

How could I do it?

Comment: you need to set layout transition when applying the new size 
check out this https://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved with this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CardView cardView;
    private Boolean isCollapsed = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_view);

        final int originalDimension = Math.round(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.original_card_view_height));
        final int newDimension = Math.round(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.new_card_view_height));

        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isCollapsed){
                    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cardView, new TransitionSet()
                            .addTransition(new ChangeBounds()));

                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = cardView.getLayoutParams();
                    params.height = newDimension;
                    cardView.setLayoutParams(params);

                    isCollapsed = false;
                } else {
                    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cardView, new TransitionSet()
                            .addTransition(new ChangeBounds()));

                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = cardView.getLayoutParams();
                    params.height = originalDimension;
                    cardView.setLayoutParams(params);

                    isCollapsed = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

you need to set layout transition when applying the new size check out this developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(transitionsContainer, new TransitionSet()
    .addTransition(new ChangeBounds())
    .addTransition(new ChangeImageTransform()));

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = imageView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = expanded ? ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT : 
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);

imageView.setScaleType(expanded ? ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP : 
    ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

Source of Sample Code
https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this example is for image... I need for a cardview.

Comment: it is sample. you can do it for all views and layouts

Comment: Hey, I tried again and it worked! Please, modify your answer as the MainActivity.java in this gist, so I can accept your answer as the right one: https://gist.github.com/guuilp/85dca2bca2a89d9432674fdb37a01ca9

Comment: Not working for me : 
                    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) animatingImageview.getLayoutParams();
                    rlp.leftMargin = newLeft;
                    rlp.topMargin = newTop - space;
                    rlp.width = newWidth;
                    rlp.height = newHeight;
                    animatingImageview.setLayoutParams(rlp);